# WIndows phone app solution showing deployment error even after a successful build

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

[image: Error Snapshot - Click to view the error]

Its saying "The project needs to be deployed before it can be started.
Verify the project is selected to be deployed or deploy it explicitly by clicking one of the deployment commands in the Build Menu."

I have tried to explicitly deploy it from the build menu but its all in vain. Not able to understand whats wrong.

Comment: I have the same issue :/

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the fact that no devices are detected.
If you try to debug on a real device, it may no be detected by your computer or VS. If you use the emulator, it may be an error with the emulator (like for example, the emulator doesn't launch, so you can't deploy on nothing).

Comment: So how to launch/deploy it on emulator?

Comment: Did you launch it with the green triangle next to the emulator name? If yes, you can try to launch the emulator first and only then try to launch the debug mode.

Comment: I have the same problem , doesn't work on Device or Emulator.. seems its the deploying part that is wrong before even trying to reach the target.

Comment: If the build part passed, then the deployement error **comes** from the fact that it **couldn't reach** the target. I suggest you to try to look that way !

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Apache Cordova Tools Package.

Worked for me.